# getting maximum from two columns of two tables

Tags: sql, select

i have two tables

t1

```
id     name
1      saanu
3      abc
```

delT1

```
id    name
2     val2
4     val4
```

I have to find out maximum value of id(int) from the two tables.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
select max(maxId) from
(
    select max(id) as maxId from delT1
    union all
    select max(id) as maxId from t1
) maxes;
```

Comment: it doesnt work it gives "Incorrect syntax near ')'" error.by the way i need for ms sql server 2005

Comment: @mu is too short: that 10 seconds was where you posted correctly with an alias on the derived table...

Comment: @gbn: well, my SQL wasn't invalid, given that the op didn't specify the DBMS he is using...

Comment: @mu: UNION ALL instead of UNION saves one comparison of the two max values.

Comment: @mu: I know that you said this. But in my opinion UNION ALL is more correct than UNION, because the DISTINCT operation performed by UNION is not needed in our case. And lack of an alias wasn't a typo, because it is valid in Oracle.

Comment: @mu: BTW: I removed the `as` after the subquery. In Oracle it is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

```
select  mymax =  
    case 
        when MAX(id1) > MAX(id2) then MAX(id1) 
        when MAX(id2) > MAX(id1) then MAX(id2) 
        end 
        from table1,table2
```